# Regular expression to extract Max and Min values

Tags: javascript, regex

67 to 90 or 67 - 90. I need to check for the "-" and the "to" so i can split the values into min and maximum

Comment: Have you done any effort yourself? And what can the numbers be? Any number? As long as there is a 'to' or a '-' in between?

Comment: '10 to 20'.trim().split(/\s+(?:-|to)\s+/) other funy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing some work is encouraged on Stack Overflow -- but this is quick and easy; I think this should do it for you:
`(\d{1,3}) ?(\-|to) ?(\d{1,3})`

- `(\d{1,3})` - an integer of 1 to 3 digits (change the second number if you want larger or smaller values.
- `?` - an optional space (remove the `?` if the space isn't optional)
- `(\-|to)` - a hyphen or the word "to"
- `?` - an optional space (remove the `?` if the space isn't optional)
- `(\d{1,3})` - an integer of 1 to 3 digits (change the second number if you want larger or smaller values.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/yN4sP8/1